# How do I iterate over several lists and matrices to call a function using parallel processing in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, iteration

I have been trying to use am R function called `ipsi`, which takes arguments `(a, y, id, time, x.trt, x.out, delta.seq, nsplits)` Originally, the components of the arguments were in one dataframe (except for `delta.seq` and `nsplits` which are coded later), but my understanding is I needed to put them in separate lists, and in the case of `x.trt` and `x.out`, matrices. This function is very easy to run on one of each argument, but since I multiply imputed the dataframe 30 times before splitting it up into different elements to be taken as `ipsi` arguments, I now want to iterate over the set of elements 30 times as if there were 30 dataframes. Additionally, I want to parallelize to optimize my computing power.

I have just expanded the npcausal example:

```
n <- 500
T <- 4
time <- rep(1:T, n)
time <- list(time,time,time,time,time,time,time,time,time,time,time,time,time,time,time,
             time,time,time,time,time,time,time,time,time,time,time,time,time,time,time)
id <- rep(1:n, rep(T, n))
id <- list(id,id,id,id,id,id,id,id,id,id,id,id,id,id,id,
             id,id,id,id,id,id,id,id,id,id,id,id,id,id,id)
x.trt <- matrix(rnorm(n * T * 5), nrow = n * T)
x.trt <- list(x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,
             x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,x.trt,x.trt)
x.out <- matrix(rnorm(n * T * 5), nrow = n * T)
x.out <- list(x.out,x.out,x.out,x.out,x.out,x.out,x.out,x.out,x.out,x.out,x.out,x.out,x.out,x.out,x.out,
             x.out,x.out,x.out,x.out,x.out,x.out,x.out,x.out,x.out,x.out,x.out,x.out,x.out,x.out,x.out)
a <- rbinom(n * T, 1, .5)
a <- list(a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,
             a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a)
y <- rnorm(mean=1,n)
y <- list(y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y,
             y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y,y)
d.seq <- seq(0.1, 5, length.out = 10)
d.seq <- list(d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,
             d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,d.seq,d.seq)

set.seed(500, kind = "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
numcores <- future::availableCores()
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(numcores)
parallel::clusterEvalQ(cl, library(dplyr))
parallel::clusterEvalQ(cl, library(npcausal))
parallel::clusterExport(cl, "d.seq", envir = environment())
parallel::clusterEvalQ(cl, d.seq <- d.seq)

new_element <- parallel::parLapply(cl = cl, for(i in 1:30){
  npcausal::ipsi(a = a[[i]],
                 y = y[[i]],
                 id = id[[i]],
                 time = time[[i]],
                 x.out = x.out[[i]],
                 x.trt = x.trt[[i]],
                 delta.seq = d.seq[[i]],
                 nsplits = 10)
})
```

This actually runs, but at the end of the process it gives me an error saying that the `FUN` was missing. I knew that already, but I have no `FUN` to call besides `ipsi`. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @Mr.Flick please see the edited example above.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what the desired output is. But with `parLapply` just like `lapply` expects you to iterate over some list with some function. You seem to have have provided a list or function but instead put in a `for` loop. I'm not really sure what you are expecting that to do. Are you just trying to parallelize over those 30 iterations?

Comment: Please see the desired output by running the example from the npcausal::ipsi documentation (https://github.com/ehkennedy/npcausal/blob/master/npcausal.pdf). npcausal's author does not use dataframes as ipsi's arguments. What I have is 30 imputed dataframes and I need to find a way to input pieces of those dataframes into ipsi's arguments. So, I chopped up all 30 imputed dataframes into different objects to input into ipsi. I just can't figure out how to iterate over each object 30 times. Also, I recognize that my reproducible example's elements are just 30 copies of each object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to first figure out how to do it with a regular base-R *apply function *without* worrying about parallelization.  I suspect you can use `mapply()` for this, so something like (non confirmed):

```
res <- mapply(
  a, y, id, time, xout, x,out, x.trt, d.seq,
  FUN = function(a_i, y_i, id_i, time_i, xout_i, x,out_i, x.trt_i, d.seq_i) {
    npcausal::ipsi(a = a_i, y = y_i, id = id_i, time = time_i,
                   x.out = x.out_i, x.trt = x.trt_i, delta.seq = d.seq_i,
                   nsplits = 10)
  }
)
```

When you figured that part out, you can start thinking about parallelization.

(Disclaimer: I'm the author) If you get an `mapply()` solution to work, then the simplest would be to replace that as-is with [`future_mapply()`](https://future.apply.futureverse.org/reference/future_mapply.html) of the [**future.apply**](http://future.apply.futureverse.org/) package.  That will parallelize on your local machine if you set `plan(multisession)`.

Comment: thank you. non-parallel version works. I'll see how to adapt to parallelize.